# Expression can be a positive integer if and only p is

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

**Question:**

> If *p* is a positive integer, then $\frac{3p+25}{2p-5}$ can be a positive integer, if and only if *p* is:
>
> A) at least 3
>
> B) at least 3 and no more than 35
>
> C) no more than 35
>
> D) equal to 35
>
> E) equal to 3 or 35

I can eliminate D and E right off the bat, because if $p=5$ then the expression would be 8, a positive integer. That's pretty much it though; don't really know how to solve this.

**Answer:**

> $B$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you were given is extremely ambiguous - it is not at all clear what it means when an expression "can be" a positive integer. None of the given answers are exactly when it is a positive integer. A priori, anything "could" be an integer.

However, let us determine exactly when the expression $\frac{3p+25}{2p-5}$ is a positive integer. In order for it to be an integer at all, it must be that $$2p-5\,|\,3p+25$$
where $a|b$ means that $a$ divides $b$ - that is $\frac{b}a$ is a integer. Since the left hand side is odd, we can multiply the right hand side by two without changing divisibility. Thus, this is equivalent to
$$2p -5\,|\,6p+50.$$
We may always add a multiple of the left hand side to the right hand side without changing its truth. Adding $-6p + 15$ to both sides gives
$$2p - 5\,|\,65.$$
Thus, this is satisfied exactly when $2p-5$ is a factor of $65$. The only odd factors of $65$ are $\pm1,\pm5,\,\pm13,\,\pm65$, thus the only possible positive $p$ are $1,\,3,\,5,\,9,\,35$ and $1$ yields that the fraction is a negative integer. Thus, the only possible $p$ are $3,\,5,\,9,$ and $35$. The most restrictive answer which allows this is B.

Answer (score 2):

The function $\frac{3p+25}{2p-5}$ *when treated as a continuous function* is decreasing from the vertical asymptote at $p=\frac52$ towards $\frac32$ as $p\rightarrow\infty$. The last natural number value this expression can possibly assume on the way down is 2, and that is attained when $p=35$, which gives the upper bound in the answer. We now note that the expression is negative if $p<\frac52$, so *p* must be at least 3 (the lower bound) and the expression is fortunately a natural number (34) at this point. Hence the bounds on *p* are $3\le p\le35$, as the correct answer says.

Comment: How do you know that "The last natural number value this expression can possibly assume on the way down is 2"?

Comment: If $p>35$ the result of the expression must be in $(\frac32,2)$, which can never be an integer. We can thus ignore the interval $(35,\infty)$ for _p_.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain how you know that If $p>35$ the result of the expression must be in $(\frac 32,2)$

Comment: It might be best to plot a graph of the expression $y=\frac{3p+25}{2p-5}$ (you can use Desmos or Wolfram Alpha for this). The expression has the same shape as the $y=1/p$ graph, but its horizontal asymptote is $y=\frac32$, as the $3x$ and $2x$ terms come to dominate at large _p_. Then we note that $y(35)=2>\frac32$ and _y_ is strictly decreasing from this point on.